# how to mark invoice as paid in microsoft dynamics crm using custom invoice paid button on ribbon?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am new in Dynamics CRM and trying to perform a task.
I've Created a custom button on Invoice form as "Mark Paid" and hided the previous already exist button "Invoice Paid". I want to perform some extra function to this "Mark paid" button and I have performed them well except this problem:-
There are four function which I am calling when clicking on "Mark Paid" button
one of these function is MarkPaid(); all these functions are javascript functions. here is my code for MarkPaid() function :

```
function MarkPaid() {
if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty()) {
    alert("Save the Invoice and try again");
    return;
}

var req = ""
req += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
req += "<s:Body>";
req += "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
req += "<request xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\">";
req += "<a:Parameters xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
req += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
req += "<b:key>EntityMoniker</b:key>";
req += "<b:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
req += "<a:Id>" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() + "</a:Id>";
req += "<a:LogicalName>invoice</a:LogicalName>";
req += "<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
req += "</b:value>";
req += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
req += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
req += "<b:key>State</b:key>";
req += "<b:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
req += "<a:Value>2</a:Value>";
req += "</b:value>";
req += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
req += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
req += "<b:key>Status</b:key>";
req += "<b:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
req += "<a:Value>100001</a:Value>";
req += "</b:value>";
req += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
req += "</a:Parameters>";
req += "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
req += "<a:RequestName>SetState</a:RequestName>";
req += "</request>";
req += "</Execute>";
req += "</s:Body>";
req += "</s:Envelope>";

var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + 
    "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", serverUrl, true)
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", 
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    assignResponse(req);
};
req.send(req);}

function assignResponse(req) {
if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
    else {
        alert("Error Marking Invoive Paid: " +req.responseXML);
    }
}}
```

When this function executes the invoice should mark as "Paid" and "Complete".
The code is executing but I am getting the alert box that display error message "Error making invoice paid" so i guess there is something wrong with my code.

any help is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: Try to troubleshoot your code. Put a breakpoint to assignResponse function and recheck req object - I'm pretty sure it will contain an answer.

Comment: First off, I would recommend changing from SOAP to OData as OData is much more straightforward.  SOAP should still work, but it is a little bit of a pain.  And you are correct, the req.status not equaling 200 means that the call did not succeed.  Please show us the error message, as it is extremely difficult to troubleshoot without an error message (there should be a req.ResponseXML or something similar which contains the error message)

Comment: This is my error message : - Error Marking Invoive Paid: [object XMLDocument]

Comment: Yes OData is much straight forward but I am unable to change values of header using OData, that is value of "status" field and "Status Reason".

Comment: Solved it.. It was a small mistake I named both variable as "req" in MarkPaid() function renaming any one of them solves the problem. Accept my apology for that silly question :)